# Google Analytics Acquisition Reporting Discrepancies

Tags: google-analytics

We're seeing difference numbers when comparing last year's data. Manually setting last years acquisition shows different numbers vs using the "compare to" tool. This example is minor but it's causing major issues when comparing over a longer period.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a **yellow shield** in top of third picture. Try to click on it to see if you have exceeded the sampling threshold (therefore the calculation is performed on a part of sessions and not on 100% and it is no longer accurate).

> Sampling is widely used in statistical analysis because analyzing a subset of data gives similar results to an analysis of a complete data set, but can produce these results with a smaller a computational burden and a reduced processing time.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192

Example:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I believe this is causing the discrepancy.